# why define function inside $()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across a public JavaScript fragment that has the following lines of code:

```
$(function() {
    var v1, v2;
    v1 = new V1;
    return v2 = new V2(v1);
});
```

The guts of the function are perfectly grokkable.  But what is the significance of wrapping this in a `$()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$(fn)` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(fn)`.

Comment: But, nevertheless, defining a function on document ready doesn't make much sense, right? It's just a defintion.

Comment: It's a function *expression*, not just a definition. The code means "use this function, defined here inline, as a handler for the `ready` event."

Comment: Here's a good article on function declarations vs. expressions: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Answer (score 4):

`$(function() {...});` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

This means code inside will be executed as soon as DOM is ready. BTW its jquery syntax, there is no really pure javascript equivalent. It is not  equivalent to `window.onload = function(){...}` which in jquery would be wrote: `$(window).load(function(){...});` .

Don't be fooled by auto called anonymous function used in javascript:

```
(function(){...})()
```

or 
    `(function(){...}())`

Comment: It is equivalent to `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn, false);`

Comment: @BrunoLM It's not that simple. Not all browsers support that. But you're right otherwise

Answer (score 1):

`$( fn )` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready( fn )`, which executes `fn` when the DOMContent is loaded.

In `.ready` docs you can see that these 3 are equivalent

```
$(document).ready(handler)
$().ready(handler) // this one is not recommended
$(handler)
```

With pure Javascript you could achieve the same behavior using

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn, false);
```

jQuery docs:

- [.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

[An example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufg7S/)

Answer (score 0):

That notation is alias for `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`